# How to use edit text without extending Activity

Tags: java, android

I'm making a game and trying to make the keyboard pop up when they touch a certain area.
I'm extending a class called Screen already and can't extend Activity I know about edit text but doesn't work for me.  Is their another way around this? or unless You can get Edit Text to work here cause Ive been trying and no luck.`package com.rmjr42.math4kidz;

```
import java.util.List;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.rmjr42.framework.Game;
import com.rmjr42.framework.Graphics;
import com.rmjr42.framework.Image;
import com.rmjr42.framework.Screen;
import com.rmjr42.framework.Graphics.ImageFormat;
import com.rmjr42.framework.Input.TouchEvent;

public class GameScreenCount extends Screen {
    //Math4Kidz keyboard=new Math4Kidz();
    //  EditText text;
    //Surface s=new Surface();
    enum GameState {
        Ready, Running, Paused, GameOver
    }
    GameState state = GameState.Ready;
    // Variable Setup   
    Paint paint, paint2;

    public GameScreenCount(Game game) {
        super(game);
        //  Looper.prepare();
        // Initialize game objects here

        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();

        NewImage pic=new NewImage();


        Assets.background = g.newImage(pic.randombackground(), ImageFormat.RGB565);
        //get one random
        Assets.pic1=g.newImage(pic.singleImage(),ImageFormat.RGB565);

        // Defining a paint object
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextSize(70);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        paint2 = new Paint();
        paint2.setTextSize(100);
        paint2.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        paint2.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint2.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    }




    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        List<TouchEvent> touchEvents = game.getInput().getTouchEvents();



        if (state == GameState.Ready)
            updateReady(touchEvents);
        if (state == GameState.Running)
            updateRunning(touchEvents, deltaTime);
        if (state == GameState.Paused)
            updatePaused(touchEvents);
        if (state == GameState.GameOver)
            updateGameOver(touchEvents);
    }

    private void updateReady(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents) {

        state = GameState.Running;
    }

    private void updateRunning(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents, float deltaTime) {



        // 1. All touch input is handled here:
        int len = touchEvents.size();
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);

            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {
                if (inBounds(event, 300, 100, 200, 200)) {
                    //Looper.prepare();//EDIT TEXT SHOULD GO HERE


                    //game.setScreen(new GameScreenCount(game));
                }

            }
        }





    }

    private boolean inBounds(TouchEvent event, int x, int y, int width,
            int height) {
        if (event.x > x && event.x < x + width - 1 && event.y > y
                && event.y < y + height - 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private void updatePaused(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents) {
        int len = touchEvents.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {
                if (inBounds(event, 0, 0, 800, 240)){

                    if (!inBounds(event, 0, 0, 35, 35)){
                        resume();}
                }

                if (inBounds(event, 0, 240, 800, 240)){
                    nullify();
                    goToMenu();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateGameOver(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents) {
        int len = touchEvents.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN) {
                if (inBounds(event, 0, 0, 800, 480)) {
                    nullify();
                    game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

    }







    @Override
    public void paint(float deltaTime) {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();

        g.drawImage(Assets.background, 0, 0);
        g.drawImage(Assets.pic1, 300, 100);
        g.drawString("How many are there ? ", 400, 400, paint);


        // Secondly, draw the UI above the game elements.

        if (state == GameState.Paused)
            drawPausedUI();
        if (state == GameState.GameOver)
            drawGameOverUI();

    }


    private void nullify() {
        paint = null;
        // Call garbage collector to clean up memory.
        System.gc();


    }
    private void drawPausedUI() {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
        // Darken the entire screen so you can display the Paused screen.
        g.drawARGB(155, 0, 0, 0);
        g.drawString("Resume", 400, 165, paint2);
        g.drawString("Menu", 400, 360, paint2);
    }

    private void drawGameOverUI() {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 1281, 801, Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("GAME OVER.", 400, 240, paint2);
        g.drawString("Tap to return.", 400, 290, paint);

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        if (state == GameState.Running)
            state = GameState.Paused;

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        if (state == GameState.Paused)
            state = GameState.Running;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    @Override
    public void backButton() {
        pause();
    }

    private void goToMenu() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));

    }


}
```

Comment: we are getting you ,what u r trying to say.....you have screen class for edit text or what

Comment: How about having Screen extend Activity? You need to be a bit more clear, show us what you are trying (codewise), and why it's not working.

Comment: Some code would be good for understand what you mean

Answer (score 1):

Its a lot of work, especially if you want to work well with any keyboard.

Android has an Input Method Framework that allows classes to interact with the keyboard.  Half of it is implemented by the keyboard, half by the edit field.  You'd need to do that second half.  The main interface you'd need to implement is

```
android.view.inputmethod.InputMethod
```

Take a look at that and the rest of the package.